# In Codeigniter, Twig project always to refresh cache

Tags: twig, codeigniter-3

In Codeigniter 3.0.6, Twig 1.24.0 project if in twig code I would like to clear all cache on any page reload.
In some cases it seems to me, that after I modify some twig and reload page by CTRL+R, the new changes were not applied to this page.
After I mannually delete twig files it works ok.

twig is included to project as library

```
https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig:
        $twig_config = array();
        $this->load->library('twig', $twig_config);
        $twig_Environment = $this->twig->getTwig();
```

$this->config is filled with :

```
$this->config::Array
(
    [paths] => Array
        (
            [0] => /mnt/diskD_Work/wwwroot/tb/application/views/
        )

    [cache] => /mnt/diskD_Work/wwwroot/tb/application/cache/twig
)
```

In $twig_Environment object output:

```
$twig_Environment::Twig_Environment Object
(
    [charset:protected] => UTF-8
    [loader:protected] => Twig_Loader_Filesystem Object
        (
            [paths:protected] => Array
                (
                    [__main__] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /mnt/diskD_Work/wwwroot/tb/application/views
                        )

                )

            [cache:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [errorCache:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [debug:protected] => 
    [autoReload:protected] => 
    [cache:protected] => Twig_Cache_Filesystem Object
        (
            [directory:Twig_Cache_Filesystem:private] => /mnt/diskD_Work/wwwroot/tb/application/cache/twig/
            [options:Twig_Cache_Filesystem:private] => 0
        )
```

In codeigniter-ss-twig object I see :

```
$debug= true; // for development envierement of CI project.
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($this->loader, [
  'cache'      => $this->config['cache'],
  'debug'      => $debug,
  'strict_variables'      => $debug,
  'autoescape' => TRUE,
]);
```

If there are some more options/tuning to update cache any time I reload my page?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `auto_reload`, based on your code this should active this option:

```
$debug= true; // for development envierement of CI project.
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($this->loader, [
  'cache'                 => $this->config['cache'],
  'debug'                 => $debug,
  'strict_variables'      => $debug,
  'autoescape'            => TRUE,
  'auto_reload'           => TRUE,
]);
```

---

It is strange that `auto_reload` is not activated though, because by default `auto_reload` depends on the option `debug` if you don't set it manually

> When developing with Twig, it's useful to recompile the template
>   whenever the source code changes. If you don't provide a value for the
>   auto_reload option, it will be determined automatically based on the
>   debug value.